# What are the best practices for exception handling in n-tier applications?

Tags: c#, architecture, mvvm

What are the best practices for exception handling in n-tier applications?

The application is a [fat client](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fat_client) based on MVVM pattern with .NET framework.

Comment: you don't give any details about the programming platform, dbb, etc. please detail,

best regards,

Comment: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=8CA8EB6E-6F4A-43DF-ADEB-8F22CA173E02&displaylang=en

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only advice I can give is that the exception and overall error handling should be taken care at the design level, and not at the implementation level. Making sure that at least a proper framework is at place for error-handling is important. Adding exception code later, most probably will need the design change and hence many changes in the code than expected.

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be a pretty hard question, I asked [about the same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/242587/exception-handling-architecture) at stackoverlfow and [this article](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/exceptions-in-the-rainforest.html) came closest to what I wanted.

Specifics for MVVM I haven't seen.